# Swing removed from JDK?

Tags: java, swing, swing-app-framework

"JSR-296 (Swing Application Framework) is no longer developed and will not become part of the offical Java Development Kit as was originally planned. You can still use the Swing Application Framework library as it is, but no further development is expected."

So... What to do? New API replacing it?

Comment: Oracle have stated that they will focusing most of their future GUI effort on JavaFX rather than Swing, but it's safe to assume that Swing will never be removed from the JDK

Comment: From what I've heard JavaFX rocks.  I'll have to look into it.  It's built on top of swing IIRC, so I'm sure swing will continue to be developed.

Comment: JavaFX is waste of time and money (like whole applets), nobody wants it unless some mirracle happens

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The swing application framework was a project to create an application framework on top of the swing GUI widget library. IIRC It had some of the same functionality that http://swinglabs.org/ has. It was intended that future versions of Java would ship with it.

It is not the same thing as the swing GUI widget library which already ships with Java.

More details on the difference between an application framework and the GUI widget library can been found in [this interview with the lead for the JSR](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/swingframework.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can try **BSAF** (http://kenai.com/projects/bsaf/pages/Home) as a replacement of Swing Application Framework. The stable version is released. Now we are working on API improvements for version 2.0. And we really need more contributors. Is anybody interested?

Comment: Why should I use BSAF? I am working on a enterprise Swing application, but I don't see what BSAF adds. I can't find anything about that on the homepage. What I'm missing most in Swing applications is a auto-update functionality similar to what Google Chrome uses, or maybe similar to what Eclipse is using.

Comment: @Jonas: Notice the name "*better* Swing Application Framework". Illya's ansqwer is perfectly valid and more to the point than the one you accepted.

Comment: @Rekin: This is not my question and I have not accepted any answer. I'm just asking about the framework since he seem to be involved in it.